# What is the name of this "ancilla based" process to implement gates

Tags: quantum-gate, teleportation, terminology-and-notation

I just want to know if there is a specific name for the implementation of a gate on the top qubit with the help of the bottom qubit, represented on this image:

[image]

It looks like gate teleportation but it is not as you do not need Bell states. The ancilla state is: $|A_{\theta}\rangle \equiv U_z(\theta) |+ \rangle$

You can find such circuit in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504218) (page 28).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the circuit on which the *magic state model* is based. As they say in the linked paper, such a circuit is often called a *gadget*, more specifically a *state injection gadget*.

The reason why such gadgets are useful is that they allow to effectively implement a gate from the $k$-th level of the Clifford hierarchy using a special resource state and gates from the $(k-1)$-th level only.
Originally, this was shown using actual gate teleportation circuits (see [Gottesman and Chuang 1999](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9908010v1)).
Later it was realised that for *diagonal* gates in the Clifford hierarchy, this primitive can be done without actually using teleportation, in particular without the use of Bell states (see [Zhou, Leung, and Chuang 2000](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0002039)).
Because of the historical origin, these gadget are sometimes called "(One-bit) gate teleportation", e.g. in [Zeng, Chen, and Chuang 2008](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.77.042313).

The resource state, $|A_\theta\rangle$ in your question, is called a *magic state* in this context.
With help of magic states, universal fault-tolerant quantum computing is possible already for $k=3$.
This is because the second level of the hierarchy is exactly the Clifford group which, together with any gate outside the group, yields an universal gate set.
The famous choice $T=U_z(\pi/4)$ is in the third level of the Clifford hierarchy and can be implemented using a gadget and the magic state $|T\rangle = |0\rangle + e^{i\pi/4}|1\rangle$.
The magic state model is fault-tolerant since Clifford gates can be made fault-tolerant using a suitable quantum code, and thus the state injection gadget is fault-tolerant, too.

Answer (score 2):

I still call this gate teleportation. It's technically not quite right since the qubit doesn't move as part of applying the operation, it doesn't teleport, but it's basically the same. It's a few ZX calculus identities away. Basically it's like saying "instead of measuring A xor B and keeping B xor (B xor A), I measure A xor B and keep A".

You can see me using this style in eg. https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.08916

[image: ccz]